# Application crashes with <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false"> in config.xml

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In iOS cordova based app, the application crashes with below error in console

**Assertion failure in -[CDVConfigParser parser:parseErrorOccurred:], /Users/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVConfigParser.m:85**

Terminating app due to uncaught exception **'NSInternalInconsistencyException'**, reason: 'config.xml parse error line 41 col 47'

```
In line 41 : I have below line in config.xml

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false">
```

It crashes on only with iOS 6.X.X versions but works fine with iOS 8.0 and above versions

I m new to cordova plugins .Anyone please help me out to fix this crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription is used  for accessing the user’s location information is available from iOS 8 and above version ..

The app crashes due to usage of NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in config.xml

Instead you can use **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** value in **info.plist** and remove  below line if you have used in config.xml

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false">
    <array>
        <string>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</string>
    </array>
```

for more: [Refer this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26)

Comment: thank you.. this solved my application crash with iOS 6

Answer (score 1):

This is because of new update in iOS 8.0.

Write below condition where you are taken permission for location update.

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

**#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)**

Comment: can you please let me know how to use this with config.xml file?As my application is Cordova based hybrid app

Comment: @Sujania actually I don't have that much knowledge in Cordova. But I know the reason for crashing. It' because of new changes while user take location update permission from app user. So you have to mention condition for that.

Comment: thank you for the reason of crash...I will try to fix with this validation in js